# Website not coming in Google local listing?

Tags: local-seo, google-local-search

so i have a website which comes up in Google local listing for the keyword "plastic surgery in mycityname" but does not come up when i enter "plastic surgery mycityname". Notice the missing word "in". Though the website comes up in organic search at 1st and 2nd position. What could be the reason for that? Is this algorithm driven or am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Now a days local listings are all about Google My Business. Have you set it up, verified it, etc?
In case you have not, this would help a lot.

Comment: I have and i also have lot of reviews. By local listing i mean Google my business listing.